# How to switch column position with bootstrap (desktop / smartphone)?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I do the following? Push / Pull?

Desktop:

[image: Desktop]

Smartphone:

[image: Smartphone]

I started with this.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-center">
        Some Small Object
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
        Some Larger Object
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-center">
        Some Small Object
</div></div>
```

**Solution (03-21-2016):**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 text-center">
  A
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sx-push-0 col-md-3 col-md-push-6 text-center">
  C
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sx-pull-0 col-md-6 col-md-pull-3 text-center">
  B
</div></div>
```

Comment: One way is to add 2 B elements, one for mobile and one for desktop version and hide the other one when active.

Comment: You'll probably have to change the order of your elements.

Comment: @xpy Thanks, that was one fault ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Grid column reordering](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering) in the [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/).

> Easily change the order of our built-in grid columns with
>   `.col-md-push-*` and `.col-md-pull-*` modifier classes.

Here's a [good example](https://scotch.io/tutorials/reorder-css-columns-using-bootstrap) on how to use column reordering.

Comment: This is what I was looking for: